# What's the probability of a random segment intersect with an existing segment within a rectangle?

Tags: probability

The question is straight forward: now I have a rectangle.
The rectangle is defined by its four coordinates: (0,0), (2,0), (0,3), and (2,3).[Shown in the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0sYb.png)

Given a segment connecting points M with coordinate(1,1) and N with coordinate (1,2), the task is to randomly select two points within the rectangle. What is the probability that the segment formed by these two randomly chosen points will intersect with the given segment?

Here is my primary approach:

First due to symmetry, I will select the bottom left quadrant as the beginning point. I split the region into 5 distinct based on their different intersection location with the side of the rectangle. [(The illustration of How I split the regions.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvlry.png)

Now, the solution seems to be clear, where double integration shall easily give the answer,
for example, when the first picked point is located in region D. the probability of the formed segment intersect with MN is the area of the polygon shaded [image: The illustration of probability of second point will form an intersected segment], and we can integrate with regard to the domain of first selected point, with coordinate (a,b), denoted as o' and second random point can be denoted as o''.
$$
P(o'o''\,intersect\,with\,MN,o'\,with \,coordinate\,(a,b)|\,o'\,in\,region\,D)=f_{(o'_x,o'_y)}(a,b)=\frac{Shaded\,area}{Total\,area}=\frac{1}{6}*(\frac{3\left(b-a-1\right)}{b-2}+\frac{\left(5a-5\right)}{2b-4}-\frac{\left(b+2a-3\right)}{2a-2})
$$
$$
P(o'o''\,intersect\,with\,MN|\,o'\,in\,region\,D)=\frac{1}{6}*\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}b}\left(\frac{3\left(b-a-1\right)}{b-2}+\frac{\left(5a-5\right)}{2b-4}-\frac{\left(b+2a-3\right)}{2a-2}\right)da\right)db = \frac{\left(-14\ln\left(2\right)+43\right)}{192} \approx0.1734
$$

Of course, different regions (i.e. ABCDE) can have different representation in this probability, the process is trivial and I will just use region D as an example here.

Here comes my problem, when I was checking my results by iterating the process in computer, I found that **for each single point, the probability is correctly calculated, however, the integrated result is very different from the iterated results**. For example, running the following R code for simulation:

```
iter = 50000
for (i in 1:iter) {
  # ## Region A
  # first_y = runif(1,min = 1, max = 1.5)
  # first_x = runif(1,min = 0, max = first_y-1)
  # ## Region B1
  # first_x = runif(1,min = 0, max = 0.5)
  # first_y = runif(1,min = 1, max = 1+first_x)
  # ## Region B2
  # first_x = runif(1,min = 0.5, max = 1)
  # first_y = runif(1,min = 1, max = 2-first_x )
  # ## Region C
  # first_x = runif(1,min = 0.5, max = 1)
  # first_y = runif(1,min = 2-first_x, max = 1.5)
  # ## Region D
  first_y = runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)
  first_x = runif(1, min = 0, max = 1 / 2 + 1 / 2 * first_y)
  ## Region E
  # first_x = runif(1,min = 0.5, max = 1)
  # first_y = runif(1,min = 0, max = 2*first_x-1)
  cor_fir = c(first_x , first_y)
  # randmise second point
  sec_x = runif(1, min = 0, max = 2)
  sec_y = runif(1, min = 0, max = 3)
  cor_sec = c(sec_x ,
              sec_y)
  
  slope =  (cor_sec[2] - cor_fir[2]) / (cor_sec[1] - cor_fir[1])
  y_intercept = -slope * cor_sec[1]  + cor_sec[2]
  if ((y_intercept + slope * 1) >= 1 &
      (y_intercept + slope * 1) <= 2 &
      (max(cor_sec[1], cor_fir[1]) >= 1) &
      (min(cor_sec[1], cor_fir[1]) <= 1)) {
    count = count + 1
  }
}
count
count / iter
```

Give an numeric value around 22% of the segments o'o'' will intersect with MN, given o' is in region D, which is very different from the probability above. But for individual points (Given o' coordinate (a,b)), the probability is calculated correctly(i.e. theoretical value close to iterated results):

```
a = 0.7
b = 0.8
theoritical_prob = (3*(b-a-1)/(b-2)+(5*a-5)/(2*b-4)-(b+2*a-3)/(2*a-2))/6
theoritical_prob
count = 0
iter = 100000
for (i in 1:iter) {
  # ## Region A
  # first_y = runif(1,min = 1, max = 1.5)
  # first_x = runif(1,min = 0, max = first_y-1)
  # ## Region B1
  # first_x = runif(1,min = 0, max = 0.5)
  # first_y = runif(1,min = 1, max = 1+first_x)
  # ## Region B2
  # first_x = runif(1,min = 0.5, max = 1)
  # first_y = runif(1,min = 1, max = 2-first_x )
  # ## Region C
  # first_x = runif(1,min = 0.5, max = 1)
  # first_y = runif(1,min = 2-first_x, max = 1.5)
  # ## Region D
  first_y = b
  first_x = a
  ## Region E
  # first_x = runif(1,min = 0.5, max = 1)
  # first_y = runif(1,min = 0, max = 2*first_x-1)
  cor_fir = c(first_x , first_y)
  # randmise second point
  sec_x = runif(1, min = 0, max = 2)
  sec_y = runif(1, min = 0, max = 3)
  cor_sec = c(sec_x ,
              sec_y)
  
  slope =  (cor_sec[2] - cor_fir[2]) / (cor_sec[1] - cor_fir[1])
  y_intercept = -slope * cor_sec[1]  + cor_sec[2]
  if ((y_intercept + slope * 1) >= 1 &
      (y_intercept + slope * 1) <= 2 &
      (max(cor_sec[1], cor_fir[1]) >= 1) &
      (min(cor_sec[1], cor_fir[1]) <= 1)) {
    count = count + 1
  }
}
count
count / iter
error = abs(count / iter-theoritical_prob)
error
```

Can anyone help me with that? So much appreciated!

Comment: With the method of Mote-Carlo the probalility found is 0.2314... 
Each "run" consists in random drawing of the coordinates of four points A,B,C,D located on a rectangular domain. For each "run" one check if the segments AB and CD intersect or not. This is repeated a large number of times (more than hundred million for example). The computed probalility is the total number of intersections divided by the total number of "runs". Changing the size of the domain doesn't change the result

Comment: Using the Monte-Carlo method to compute the probability in various cases of size and shape of the domain where the points are randomly drawn one observes this : The probability doesn't change when the size change (with the same shape). The probability changes when the shape changes. For example in case of rectangular domains the computed probability is 0.23148... In case of elliptic domains the computed probability is 0.23482... The next digit is still fluctuating after one milliard of "runs". More accuracy would need too long computation time.